# AmCharts (type = stock) custom zoomToIndexes(start, end) not working

Tags: amcharts

I am trying to zoom to particular set of data within the stock graph using external button (operated by Jquery click listener). Whenever I try to change the zoom, it gives an error " chart.zoomToIndexes is not a function"

I am trying to change the zoom with this code.

```
  $( ".zoom" ).click(function() {
  console.log("zoom is clicked");
  chart.zoomToIndexes(0, 20);
```

});

Comment: There's not enough of a sample here to really help. It's apparent `chart` is an object at that point, looks like the code should work, but without any other code we can't really tell what's going on. Would you mind providing a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help?

Comment: thanks... the code mentioned below works... yes chart is the object. zoom method works on "Stock charts"

Answer (score 2):

Stock charts do not have the `zoomToIndexes` method; they only have the [`zoom`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#zoom) method, which accepts the start date and end date. You can replicate zoomToIndexes by using your mainDataSet's dataProvider categoryField values directly at your desired indices:

```
$(".zoom").click(function() {
  var dataSet = chart.mainDataSet;
  var categoryField = dataSet.categoryField;
  chart.zoom(dataSet.dataProvider[0][categoryField], dataSet.dataProvider[20][categoryField]); 
});
```

The above assumes your categoryField values are date objects. If they're string-based dates, you need to convert them first using [`AmCharts.stringToDate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmCharts#stringToDate) using the [`dataDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#dataDateFormat) supported format strings listed [here](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/).